# Cuando despliego mi proyecto react, recibo el mensaje de error 404

Tags: reactjs, github, vite, github-pages

Cuando despliego mi proyecto en github pages, no se muestra. Solamente muestra una pantalla blanca y un mensaje de error en la terminal. No sé por qué sucede esto y es la primera vez que estoy teniendo este problema

Aquí está el enlace de la repo: https://github.com/AimarBustamante/pet_care_portal
También, el enlace de la página web: https://aimarbustamante.github.io/pet_care_portal/

Y este es el mensaje de error que estoy recibiendo.
[image: Mensaje de error]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.